# How to use MultiTouch in Android ? Simple way please

Tags: android, eclipse, touch, surfaceview, multi-touch

I am a near begginer and I have developed a simple 2D game on surfaceView using Canvas

However, my game now requires multiTouch but my touch method only gets one touch not any more

It would be great if you answered with a simple detailed answer, because I have been researching this and I am so confused about this.

If it makes it easier, I won't be needing more than 2 touches, so I only need a maximum of 2 touches together..

below is my code for my current singular touch...

Thanks A LOT :)

```
public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    x = event.getX (); // with this I am getting the x position of one singular point of where the curse would be
    y = event.getY ();

    if (event.getAction () == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        fingerTouching = true; //this is just for one, how would I do it for all the cursors ? in like a for loop?
        return true;
    }

    if (event.getAction () == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        fingerTouching = false;
        return false;
    }

    if (event.getAction () == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
    {
        fingerMoving = true;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the Android documentation here?

[Handling Multi-Touch Gestures](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use next events for detect more touches:

```
MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP
```

And this, to get coordinates:

```
if (event.getPointerCount()>1) {
    x[1] = event.getX(1);
    y[1] = event.getY(1);
}
x[0] = event.getX(0);
y[0] = event.getY(0);
```

Comment: ok so what about the detects for each pointer? how do i know if that specific pointer is touching or no? is this right? --->
    if (event.getAction () == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN [1])
    {
        fingerTouching [1] = false;
        return false;
    }